# PDO: setAttribute() has no effect with dblib and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I am connecting to an SQL Server database (SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 x64) from a Linux server running PHP 5.3.19 using the following lines:

```
$this->dbLink = new PDO(
    'dblib:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->database,
    $this->user,
    $this->password,
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    )
);
```

The connection works perfectly fine, except that ATTR_ERRMODE works as ERRMODE_WARNING, no matter what I do.

I have tried setting it using `$this->dbLink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right before the query call, but it has no effect.

If I use `getAttribute()`, I can confirm that PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE is indeed set to `int(2)` (ERRMODE_EXCEPTION), but I still get warnings and PHP keeps chugging along with obviously wrong queries.

Comment: Additional data: FreeTDS is used (according to phpinfo()). In my freeTDS config (/etc/freetds.conf), I found that 4.2 is the default version. It's compatible, but awfully limited compared to 7.2, which is used by SQL Server 2005 and 2008. I'll see with the sysadmin if this configuration can be changed.

Comment: I hope you are using proper `try{}catch(){}` method to handle the exceptions, otherwise I can't tell what the problem might be. What do you get when you pass invalid query, what does the error say?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown at all. If I pass an invalid query, it will keep going with a warning. I temporarily resolved to a simply sanity check (if query===false), but otherwise PHP kept chugging along.

Comment: What does the error say? have you checked your error log file? and is display on ? You can check these things for better refractoring

Comment: Standard PDO warnings: `PHP Warning:  Database::query(): message: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint...`. I have try/catch statements that get bypassed, but my warnings are caught by the log file, as expected.

It behaves exactly as if I used ERRMODE_WARNING.

Comment: Well then, this means the problem is with your query and not with PDO. try it with `prepare()` and it will get caught in the exception. You should post your entire code related to the exception so we can see if there is something wrong going on

Comment: I know that my query is wrong. I have deliberately used a wrong query to test exception handling. My problem is that I get warning instead of exceptions.

There is no extra code, just a standard call to prepare() and execute(). No matter what I call, I should be getting exceptions, not warnings.

Comment: I have found a similar bug on bugs.php.net: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37285

Comment: I suppose it's a bug, in which case you should open a new report, because that one seems to be outdatted.

Comment: What about lowering the error mode to ERRMODE_WARNING?

Comment: Have you tried setting it as an attribute rather than a driver option? (it will throw a `PDOException` if the constructor fails anyway) `$this->dbLink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` May not make any odds looking at the bug report ... but that was from like 8 years ago *shrugs*

Comment: Yes, I have. In both cases, "getAttribute" returns the correct value, but nothing changes.

As for the bug report, I wouldn't be surprised if nothing changed, considering I'm using the ridiculously buggy FreeTDS/dblib driver.

Comment: See also [this PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63812) for a hint.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PDO_DBLIB is an experimental extension and should not be used for production environments.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

If you can, you should use PDO_SQLSRV instead:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php

Just change your connection setting from `dblib:` to the PDO_SQLSRV driver dns prefix `sqlsrv:`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.connection.php

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over that, and to make matters worse, I am on a Linux box.

Comment: U don't have control over your code, or your drivers? Perhaps if you enumerate the available drivers we could be of more assistance. Do this by calling `PDO::getAvailableDrivers` or `pdo_drivers()`